# Correlation coefficient of two variables with unequal number of data using Excel

Tags: correlation, excel

How do I find the correlation coefficient of two variables with unequal number of data using Excel? And do I use the mean as data to calculate?

Comment: to get correlation, your data will be paired. If the observation for one of the variables in a pair is missing, you'd normally exclude the other member from the calculation of the correlation.

Comment: @Glen_b's comment indicates you will need to provide more details about your data, user21489, in order for this question to be answerable.

Answer (score 2):

A correlation coefficient requires that for every x-value there be a y-value ... otherwise, how should I know how much value of y to attribute to x?  For example, if you're trying to determine how much height correlates with age, you need a collection of heights and ages.  Knowing that a person is 5'5" tall doesn't help at all if you don't know how old that person is.

Do you mean that you have several y values for each of your x values? Like

> 5-year olds: 36", 37" 38"
>
> 6-year olds: 37", 39", 40"
> ...
> ?

If so, make a row for each y value, and include its corresponding x-value:

> **Age** | **Height**
>
> 5 | 36
>
> 5 | 37
>
> 5 | 38
>
> 6 | 37
>
> 6 | 39
>
> 6 | 40

And then you can use CORREL()